# What is this type of chart?

Tags: javascript

I have found a chart that suits exactly what our data needs but its simply just an image, it looks like a stacked bar chart, but it works differently.

Each of the ticks along the bottom represents a group, eg hour number, and when you hover you see all that data from the group.

[image]

Does anybody have any idea what its called and even better, know any source for the chart in a java script library, d3 or similar ?

Answer (score 1):

It is a 'Stacked Horizontal Bar Graph'

http://www.storytellingwithdata.com/blog/2014/06/alternatives-to-pies

ChartJS:

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-chart-options

Option for stacked.